# Open cv 3 Python 3 AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture' Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to load a live video from my web cam using open cv v3 and Python 3.5 on Windows 10 but I always get this 'AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture' when loaded from a file. When I import cv2 using the shell, all the modules are accessible. But when I use `dir(cv2)` and run it in a file, I only see a few modules. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I access the 'VideoCapture' attr from cv2? I need help please. All the solution I find on online don't seem to work. thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of python or opencv installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix the issue but I have had a problems while using OpenCV 3.3/OpenCV 2.4 with Python 3.5. I switched to Python 2.7 and many crashes and similar errors got fixed. I use cv2.VideoCapture() in my projects and it works like a charm! (Using opencv3.3 and python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I think Shawn Mathew is right, I had multiple Python Versions installed. When I removed other versions and then I installed Anaconda with Python 3.5, I installed opencv with pip using the binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. It worked, I hope this will help someone having the same issue

NB: Don't forget to also install Microsoft C++ Redistributable from official Microsoft website